# Add the difference of two images in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am working on image processing. I want to add the difference of pixels of two images.

Suppose I have two images A, and B. I pick the first pixel of both images and store the difference value. I want to add this difference value to next pixel-difference. I try using this code, but it is not working. How can I do it?

```
A = imread('sub2.jpg');
B = imread('sub1.jpg');
tic
[rows cols] = size(A);
diff1 = 0;
for x = 1:rows
   for y = 1:cols
       diff = A(x,y)-B(x,y);
       diff1 = diff1+diff;
   end
end
disp(diff1);
toc
```

Comment: Are `A` and `B` of same size? Note also that it is not that wise naming variables after a built-in function (`diff`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks okay though, but you're better off with:

```
diff1 = sum(sum(A-B));
```

or if `B` is larger than `A`:

```
diff1 = sum(sum(A-B(1:size(A,1),1:size(A,2))));
```

This gives just one value (as your code does), I'm not sure if that really is what you want..

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one line as follows:

```
sum(sum(imsubtract(A-B)))
```

[`imsubtract`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imsubtract.html) subtracts two images and saves the difference in a matrix with the same size as `A`. Then, `sum` takes the sum of the result.

If you need absolute differences, you may use [`imabsdiff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imabsdiff.html) instead of [`imsubtract`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imsubtract.html).

Note that the values of the differences are in 0 and 255. If you want negative instances, then you should directly subtract the matrices as `A-B`.

Comment: didn't you mean `imsubtract(A,B)` instead of `imsubtract(A-B)`?